# Difference between Magento v2.3.3 and Magento v2.3.3-p1

Tags: magento2.3

I'm a little bit confusing the Difference between `Magento v2.3.3` and `Magento v2.3.3-p1`?

Can someone help me on this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The are Some Security Updates

See this [Magento 2.3.3 p1](https://community.magento.com/t5/Magento-DevBlog/Introducing-the-New-Security-only-Patch-Release/ba-p/141287?_ga=2.246424132.112094036.1583232637-1794083710.1583232637)

Answer (score 1):

it's Security-only patches.
With the release of Magento 2.3.3, Magento introduced a new type of patch: the security-only patch. Patch 2.3.3-p1 includes the significant security fixes

(A hot fix provides a fix to a released version of Magento that addresses a specific problem or bug.) Merchants deploying Magento 2.3.3 can apply patch 2.3.3-p1 to immediately take advantage of time-sensitive security fixes without investing the time required to install Magento 2.3.4.